# Python SQLAlchemy why am I getting a NoReferencedTableError on a FK

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-restful

I've inherited a SQLAlchemy project and need some assistance figuring out why one relationship does not appear to be behaving like all the others. Our orm models are generated by a script and as such I would assume all would either work or not.

When I try to insert on the table with the FK I receive the below error message:

Foreign key associated with column 'RenewalBatchGroup.renewalbatchfrequencyid' could not find table 'RenewalBatchFrequency' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'renewalbatchfrequencyid'

In the below code, as it is, I get the NoReferencedTableError exception. However if I change the import from Frequency importing Group to the other way around, it does work.

IE: 
Remove the following from RenewalBatchFrequency.py
"from app.orm.LROCustomer.dbo.RenewalBatchGroup import RenewalBatchGroup"

and add the following to RenewalBatchGroup.py
from app.orm.LROCustomer.dbo.RenewalBatchFrequency import RenewalBatchFrequency

I need to know why this relationship is behaving differently from other relationships like the RenewalBatch relationship. It's setup the exact same way.

RenewalBatchGroup.py

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import *
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from app.DatabaseCore import Base
from Utils.DateTimeUtils import getDateTimeString
from app.orm.LROCustomer.dbo.RenewalBatch import RenewalBatch
from app.orm.LROCustomer.dbo.RenewalBatchGroupProperty import RenewalBatchGroupProperty


class RenewalBatchGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RenewalBatchGroup'
    __table_args__ = {'implicit_returning': False}  # http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#triggers

    batchleadtime = Column(SMALLINT)
    batchsize = Column(SMALLINT)
    groupname = Column(VARCHAR(400))
    offerstatusid = Column(INTEGER)
    renewalbatchfrequencyid = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('RenewalBatchFrequency.renewalbatchfrequencyid'))
    renewalbatchfrequencyvalue = Column(VARCHAR(100))
    renewalbatchgroupid = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    updateuser = Column(VARCHAR(254))

    RenewalBatches = relationship("RenewalBatch", backref="RenewalBatchGroup")
    RenewalBatchGroupPropertys = relationship("RenewalBatchGroupProperty", backref="RenewalBatchGroup")

    def jsonify(self):
        return {"batchleadtime": self.batchleadtime,
                "batchsize": self.batchsize,
                "groupname": self.groupname,
                "offerstatusid": self.offerstatusid,
                "renewalbatchfrequencyid": self.renewalbatchfrequencyid,
                "renewalbatchfrequencyvalue": self.renewalbatchfrequencyvalue,
                "renewalbatchgroupid": self.renewalbatchgroupid,
                "updateuser": self.updateuser
                }

    def update(self, row):
        self.batchleadtime = row.batchleadtime
        self.batchsize = row.batchsize
        self.groupname = row.groupname
        self.offerstatusid = row.offerstatusid
        self.renewalbatchfrequencyid = row.renewalbatchfrequencyid
        self.renewalbatchfrequencyvalue = row.renewalbatchfrequencyvalue
        self.updateuser = row.updateuser
```

RenewalBatchFrequency.py

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import *
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from app.DatabaseCore import Base
from Utils.DateTimeUtils import getDateTimeString
from app.orm.LROCustomer.dbo.RenewalBatchGroup import RenewalBatchGroup


class RenewalBatchFrequency(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RenewalBatchFrequency'
    __table_args__ = {'implicit_returning': False}  # http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#triggers

    name = Column(VARCHAR(100))
    renewalbatchfrequencyid = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)

    RenewalBatchGroups = relationship("RenewalBatchGroup", backref="RenewalBatchFrequency")

    def jsonify(self):
        return {"name": self.name,
                "renewalbatchfrequencyid": self.renewalbatchfrequencyid
                }

    def update(self, row):
        self.name = row.name
```

If any other information is needed just let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing to get this error. Are you running some command on the command line? Would be great to know what that is.

Comment: Calling an API to insert a new record. Looks like I've found a solution this morning though.

Comment: Does the 'from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import *' needs to be * or can you specify what you need from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, I can solve the issue by reversing the import statement. That's contrary to all the other relationships. I can only assume there is a circular reference somehow with the other relationships that SQLAlchemy is working out.

The way that I solved this issue is to put all of my model imports into the __ init__.py file and thus every model has access to all models. Now when I generate a new model I just need to make sure it's added to the __ init__.py file and I should be good to go.

A very frustrating experience.